# Why does printf output not appear right away when stepping through the code?

Tags: c, breakpoints, anjuta

I'm using Anjuta and gdb on Fedora 20 and created a C Makefile project. The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
°   printf ("1");
°   printf ("2");
°   printf ("3");

    return (0);
}
```

° means I set a breakpoint at that position.

Now when I debug the code, there's no output while the current line is one of these printf-functions. Only when I exit main '123' appears in the terminal.

If I add \n to the second printf argument, then '12' appears as output when I move from breakpoint 2 to the 3rd one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, stdout is line buffered when writing to a terminal, fully buffered when writing to any other type of stream. Since you're not printing any newlines, the output is being buffered. You can change the buffering mode with `setbuf()`, end each string with newline, or call `fflush()` when you want printing to take plac.

Answer (score 4):

This is because printf writes to stdout which happens to be buffered. For more details see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/2036917)

Comment: Its always buffered... not "happens to be"

Comment: Well, you can make it unbuffered by calling setbuf()

Comment: @texasbruce stdout is _not_ always buffered.  1st, it is implementation defined.  2nd If buffered or not, the mode can be changed..

Answer (score 4):

Add fflush(stdout) after each printf. Your output is small and remains in buffer until the progam exits.